# Git-for-Windows Mintty sys.stdout.isatty() returns False

Tags: windows, mintty

I'm using mintty via Git-for-Windows and CPython35-32. Why does Python think it's not attached to a terminal?

```
$ python -c "import sys; print(sys.stdout.isatty())"
False
```

Interestingly, I also have a problem that I can not start an interactive session of Python inside the mintty. It might be related to this issue

```
$ python
<nothingness here...>
```

Comment: https://github.com/mintty/mintty/issues/56

Answer (score 4):

[mintty's console emulation uses pipes to emulate a tty](https://github.com/mintty/mintty/issues/56#issuecomment-108887055) behind the scenes which confuses native programs checking to see if they are attached to a tty. In your case Python's `isatty()` sees stdout as being attached to pipe due to the fake tty and returns False.

This is another example of [mintty issue #56 - Improve support for native console programs](https://github.com/mintty/mintty/issues/56). The [mintty wiki entry "Input/Output interaction with alien programs"](https://github.com/mintty/mintty/wiki/Tips#inputoutput-interaction-with-alien-programs) points out you can work around the problem by using a wrapper like [winpty](https://github.com/rprichard/winpty) when running the problem program within mintty.

The git commits mentioned by @vonc only work around the problem in the git program itself - they won't impact other programs (such as Python running in git-for-window's mintty) which would need to implement git's workaround in their own source.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try that with  Git 2.12 (Q1 2017)

See [commit a9b8a09](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a9b8a09c3c30886c79133da9f48ef9f98c21c3b2) (22 Dec 2016) by [Jeff Hostetler (`jeffhostetler`)](https://github.com/jeffhostetler).
See [commit 8692483](https://github.com/git/git/commit/86924838e3d881cda2192fd79ac3a58aad75efd3) (22 Dec 2016) by [Alan Davies (`scooter6386`)](https://github.com/scooter6386).
See [commit fee807c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fee807c5f6da43ba03f4f92d832fd625ab57b0d7) (22 Dec 2016) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 58fcd54](https://github.com/git/git/commit/58fcd54853023b28a44016c06bd84fc91d2556ed), 27 Dec 2016)</sup>

> `mingw`: replace `isatty()` hack
>
> Git for Windows has carried a patch that depended on internals of MSVC runtime, but it does not work correctly with recent MSVC runtime.
>   A replacement was written originally for compiling with VC++.
>
> The patch in this message is a backport of that replacement, and it also fixes the previous attempt to make `isatty()` tell that `/dev/null` is *not* an interactive terminal.